# changing css in bootstrap 4 to customize website

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am making a bootstrap site for my sister and everytime i want to change css it works or 90% of the time it don't work.

I made a new file "style.css" to overwrite bootstrap i placed it under all the other tags in my  and it still doesn't work can someone explain please?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
<section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">About</h2>
      <hr class=" mb-5">
      <div class="row">
          <p class="lead">some text...</p>
          <p class="lead">some text...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center mt-4">
        <a class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-download mr-2"></i>
          Download Now!
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

than i have in the bootstrap css file this line:

```
section{
padding: 6rem 0;
}
```

I want to change that to 9 rem so in my custom css file:

```
section{
padding: 9rem 0;
}
```

i does nothing ): and that is just one example maybe i do something very very stupid but i don't think so. and its not the cache.

head:

```
<head>
<!--there is some more here but not nessecary-->
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- tab icon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="img/logo_1.png">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- Plugin CSS -->
  <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--icons-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your actual HTML and CSS? It's easier to help you if you share what you have done so far

Comment: Oke i will search and edit for an example

Comment: Please share you `<head>` tag as well so we can see how you are including your files

Comment: Easiest way to debug issues like this is to right click on the element with the issue and "inspect element" and you can see what css is taking precedence and which css is getting overridden.

Comment: Yes i am trying that but then the bootstrap css is not getting overwritten and that is what i want

Comment: But is the Bootstrap overriding your custom CSS?  Does it show your custom CSS with a strikethrough line through it?

Comment: Yes sometimes it shows my custom css with a strike through.

Comment: Make sure your custom CSS file is being loaded after the Bootstrap one.  Try adding an `!important` at the end of one of your custom rules that is being overridden and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, there are a couple things on your file that might fix your issue, it would be better to avoid using `!important` unless you really don't have another choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your same imports I don't see Bootstrap's CSS having any paddings on the `section` tag, the styles you defined are applying correctly, maybe it's a different stylesheet that's causing this?

Also note you are importing Bootstrap CSS twice, and maybe for different versions of it? Try deleting the import you are not using. In fact, try deleting one css import at a time to see when the problem goes away, that'll at least help you find which stylesheet is overriding your styles

```css
section {
  padding: 9rem 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--there is some more here but not nessecary-->
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!--icons-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<section class="bg-primary text-white mb-0" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="text-center text-uppercase text-white">About</h2>
    <hr class=" mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="lead">some text...</p>
      <p class="lead">some text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mt-4">
      <a class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-download mr-2"></i> Download Now!
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think the problem was in the headtag like you said.

Comment: loading bootstrap twice

Comment: Great, maybe the version you had there was applying the styles with `!important` and that's why your rules were not applying even though your css file was imported after it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your webpage is still cached, try to hit ctrl + f5 to check if it is presesting. 
Otherwise just use the `!important` keyword in your css styles. down below you will find an example of how to use an !important statement.

```
.row {
  padding: 15px !important;
  margin: 10px auto !important;
}
```

An important statement overwrites files even if they come after the execution stack of the dom.

Here is some more information of the usage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types

Edit:
Be aware that the import keyword is hard to work around with when you want to change this later, for your specific case it would be fine. But if it is for bigger clients and projects, watch your important keywords ;).

Comment: I would just point out that one should be careful with `!important` rules, as they might make other parts hard to work with; but apart from that it definitely should fix any issues;

Comment: Yes, most definitely, especially with big css files. But I am reading he is making a bootstrap website for his sister, so he should not take it to heavily for this project. Thank you for the nice comment. I will adjust my answer accordingly :)

Comment: Thanks i will look into the important tag